# PHPStorm and CodeSniffer do not recognize WPCS

Tags: documentation

I'm trying to use Wordpress Coding Standards in my PHP Storm projects but I keep getting errors.

What I already did:

1. I put it in composer.json:

   "require": {
   "squizlabs/php_codesniffer" : "3.*",
   "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "2.3.0"
   }
2. I configured CodeSniffer in the QualityTools option
3. In Inspections -> PHP -> QualityTools, I put Wordpress in Coding Standard.
   [image: Image 1 - Inspection setting]

**The problem:**

Even though I've done all this, I'm still not able to evaluate the codes from WPCS. The following error is returned:

> ERROR: The file "standard=WordPress" does not exist.

When I type phpcs -i, WordPress doesn't show up either:

> The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2,
> Squiz and Zend

[image: Image 2 - PHPCS Messages]
Can someone help me?

**System details:**

PHPStorm 2020.2.1
Windows 11
Composer global installation

Comment: After you added the WPCS dependency to your `composer.json` file, did you run `composer update` or `php composer.phar update` to [*install* the dependency](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies)?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I'd clicked in Install and Update option on PHPStorm.